# Relations between not directly related tables - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are 4 tables: users, owners, groups, requests

There is no **direct** relation between owners and requests and I'm looking for a way to do something like this: $onwer->requests, to get all requests related to an owner.

Here is how things works:

Every user is in a group, each group is owned by an owner, requests will be created by users and each request is for a (related to/ within a) group.

**Tables are like this:**
owners: id,username
groups: id,name,owner_id,year
users: id,username
group_user: id,group_id,user_id
requests: id,group_id,user_id,desc

It's easy to create relation between owners and groups, or between requests and users, but how can I get all related requests to an owner? another thing is that I should be able to get all requests belong to a owner which are in a group with a **where** statement like **year=something**.

For now I'm doing something stupid like this:

*There is one to many relation between group and requests, so i can get all requests from a group.* *(group hasMany request)*

```
$groups = Group::where('owner_id', $owner_id)->get();

foreach($groups as $group)
   foreach($group->requests as $request)
      if($request->year == 2016)
          $requests[] = $request;
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `hasManyThrough`. You can `return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\Request::class, \App\Group::class);`. It kind of says "I, the owner class, have a lot of Requests through the Groups Entities". Since your `group` already have `owner_id` and your request have `group_id`, it should work.

Comment: Yes, It did the job. thank you. I really have no idea why I never read the *has many through* section in laravel docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else looking for the same thing, the concept behind this is called `hasManyThrough` by **Laravel**.

In this case, we would have the following function at the **Owner's Class Model**

```
public function requests() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\Request::Class, \App\Group::Class);
}
```

The logic here is that the `Owner` has a lot of `Requests` (1st parameter) **through** the `Group` class (2nd parameter).